# Animation Effects on a PopUp Window

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I was wondering if there is a jQuery animation that can be applied to a pop-up window when a button is pressed?

Basically have a page with a button - when the users presses this button, a popup windown appears - would like to apply some animation to this page such as zoom/fade-in if possible.

Thanks.
T

Comment: when you say "popup window", do you mean a modal overlay? if so, there are loads out there, each with their custom animation options.

what sort of stuff is displayed on the popup? is it images or text?

Comment: no, my popup window is not modal.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`show` option](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#option-show) to specify an animation to be used when the dialog is opened.